# how setup a custom port where run my hybrid app in Xcode using capacitor?

Tags: ios, xcode, port, ionic4, capacitor

Im developing a hybrid app using ionic 4 and capacitor, i read that you can set a custom port where will run your app when you are testing it in an emulator or device, and is in the capacitor.config.json, everything work in android studio SDK or real device, but, when i run my app in Xcode in mac, neither device emulator and real device work, it run over a random port every time i run it,  could be http://localhost:3177 or http://localhost:7137, etc, and i set a fixed port that always work in android, but is like xcode or something of ios is overlaping that configuration and running the app in a random port.
some idea? im working with **ionic 4, macOS 10.13.6 and Xcode 10.0**

Comment: how did you configure the port?

Comment: @jcesarmobile im using the capacitor.config.json, following the documentation, and its works running in android device or android studio, but, when i run it on IOS emulator or IOS decive (using Xcode in both cases), its like is ignoring this configuration.

here is my capacitor.config.json:
 `{
  "appId": "xxxxx",
  "appName": "xxxxx",
  "bundledWebRuntime": false,
  "webDir": "www",
  "server" : {
    "port" : 5002
  },
  "android": {
    "allowMixedContent": true,
    "captureInput": true
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

The port must be a string, not an int.

On Android it works because it's the `JSONObject` class the one that picks the value and seems that it converts the int to string, but iOS doesn't do any conversion, so it returns nil as if it wasn't configured.

Comment: it works! you are right, thanks so much! how do you realized of that? i had a lot of time with this issue! @jcesarmobile

Comment: I’m one of the Capacitor developers